# Do Windows shortcuts support very long argument lengths?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007, shortcut, maxlength

I am trying to create a shortcut (on the Desktop) that contains a long argument string (> MAX_PATH).

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states that for Unicode string the string can be longer than MAX_PATH.

The resulting shortcut is cut exactly after MAX_PATH characters (that is the `Path` + the `Arguments`).

Is there something wrong with my implementation or is this some Windows limitation?

```
procedure CreateShortcut(APath: WideString;
  AWorkingDirectory: WideString; AArguments: WideString; ADescription: WideString;
  ALinkFileName: WideString);
var
   IObject : IUnknown;
   ISLink  : IShellLinkW;
   IPFile  : IPersistFile;
begin
   IObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
   ISLink := IObject as IShellLinkW;
   ISLink.SetPath(            PWideChar(APath));
   ISLink.SetWorkingDirectory(PWideChar(AWorkingDirectory));
   ISLink.SetArguments(       PWideChar(AArguments));
   ISLink.SetDescription(     PWideChar(ADescription));
   IPFile := IObject as IPersistFile;
   IPFile.Save(PWideChar(ALinkFileName), False);
end;
```

PS: OS is Windows XP (and above).

Comment: Have you tried using the \\?\ prefix to enable long file names? For example, *\\?\D:\very\long\path* - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @David: Yes, that leads to Explorer hanging for a few seconds and the limitation is still there.

Comment: Is what gets cut off the arguments, the path or the working directory? I have a feeling you will need to use SetIDList instead of SetPath.

Comment: @David: The string you get when you combine path and arguments (what is called the "target" in the explorer dialog) get cut to 260 chars.

Comment: It seems you can not write more than 260 chars manually to the target in the Windows Explorer properties dialog, too.

Comment: I think that's a limitation in the shell dialog rather than something underlying in the shell link backing it. What happens when you execute the shortcut? Does it behave correctly?

Comment: Is it possible that `CLSID_ShellLink` you are providing is actually the one assigned to the non-unicode version, `IShellLinkA`? At least, in my part of the world there are two distinct CLSIDs for the pair of them in the registry.

Comment: How are you verifying the length of the result? If you're viewing the shortcut properties in Explorer, is it possible that the dialog box is truncating the string for display, but that the full-length string is still stored in the .lnk file?

Comment: @Andriy - Are you sure about that? There is only one `CLSID_ShellLink` in `shlguid.h`. I get two hits for a `CLSID_ShellLinkW` search, and both of them in fact define `IID_IShellLinkW`.

Comment: Tough job! Even modifying the '.lnk' does not seem to help, it reverts to MAX_PATH with next run. If you examine the `.lnk` with a hex editor, you'll notice there's a `WORD` before the argument section indicating the size of the string in characters. It's a *WORD*, *"there is no limitation on maximum string length"* should be a documentation error.

Comment: Documentation of IShellLink states: "The IShellLink interface has an ANSI version (IShellLinkA) and a Unicode version (IShellLinkW). The version that will be used depends on whether you compile for ANSI or Unicode." However, my guess is that the COM object you create supports both IShellLinkA and IShellLinkW. Personally I would instantiate this object with CoCreateInstance and I'd try to avoid using an `I` prefix on my variable names too, but that's somewhat beside the point.

Comment: @David - Thought of 'CoCreateInstance', didn't help here.. Perhaps really the difference is the application being unicode or not.

Comment: @Sertac I have now solved it - see below. The reference to `CoCreateInstance` is more one of style and taste. Actually I suggested the solution 5 hours ago!

Comment: @Sertac Concept of "Application being Unicode" not meaningful here. That only really means something for a message pump. "ANSI" apps can call Unicode interfaces and vice versa.

Comment: @Sertac: FWIW. There are two registry keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT on my Win 7, one is `{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` whose `(default)` value is `'IShellLinkA'`, the other is `{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`, and it's `'IShellLinkW'` accordingly.

Comment: @David - No joy here, 'test.out' is 262 bytes. It may work for Jens though.

Comment: @Andriy - Those are `IID_IShellLinkA` and `IID_IShellLinkW`. `CLSID_ShellLink` is `{00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}`. Jens is already using `IShellLinkW`.

Comment: @sertac that's how long it is meant to be - look at the contents you'll see it's all there.

Comment: @David - I already did, the string in your answer is '275' bytes. My test.out ends with `'67890012345'#32#13#10`. Who puts the space and the line break, I have no idea.

Comment: @Sertac definitely worked for me.

Comment: @David - I don't doubt it. :) I really think it may work for Jens, I'm testing on a 2K box here.

Comment: @Sertac 2k?! Guess that may explain things! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that this issue is in fact solely a limitation in the Explorer shell dialog. The generated shortcut file does not have a 260 character limitation. It's simply that the dialog refuse to display a Target with more characters than that. Presumably it calls `GetPath` with a fixed length buffer.

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: IShellLinkW;
  pf: IPersistFile;
begin
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLinkW, sl);
  sl.SetPath('c:\desktop\test.bat');
  sl.SetWorkingDirectory('c:\desktop\');
  sl.SetArguments(PChar(StringOfChar('x', 300)+'_the_end'));
  pf := sl as IPersistFile;
  pf.Save('c:\desktop\test.lnk', False);
end;
```

My `test.bat` looks like this:

```
echo %1> test.out
```

The resulting `test.out` goes right the way to _the_end!

Comment: I can confirm a 311 byte 'test.out' with D2007 on W7.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks all who contributed to this thread - it helped me immensely.

However, if I may, I would like to add the below information I discovered in crafting my solution:

1. On Windows 7 Enterprise ~SP1, it would seem that using [VBS to create the shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7kaky2%28v=vs.84%29) there is still a limit on maximum characters in (at least) the arguments field. I tested up to 1023 chars before it got trunicated. I presume the same limit would apply to the Delphi method likewise.
2. On Windows XP Professional ~SP3, while the VBS method will create a shortcut longer than 260 characters (lnk file contains the data), it seems to trunicate it at about this number when executing it.